# c# mark exchange email as read

Tags: c#

I need to mark emails as read on the exchange server.

I use the following to get the emails and now i need to mark them as read

```
        strQuery =
       @"<?xml version=""1.0""?> 
            <g:searchrequest xmlns:g=""DAV:""> 
                <g:sql> 
                    SELECT 
                        ""urn:schemas:mailheader:from"", ""urn:schemas:httpmail:htmldescription"" 
                    FROM 
                        ""https://********.*******.****/exchange/**.******/inbox/""  
                    WHERE  
                        ""urn:schemas:httpmail:read"" = FALSE  
                        AND ""DAV:contentclass"" = 'urn:content-classes:message'  

                    </g:sql> 
            </g:searchrequest>";
```

How do I go about doing this?

Sp

Comment: so is your question "How to delete emails" or "How to mark them as read"? Thats quite a significant difference in what your answer will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"
+ "<a:propertyupdate xmlns:a=\"DAV:\" xmlns:d=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:exch-data:\" "
+ "xmlns:b=\"urn:schemas:httpmail:\" xmlns:c=\"xml:\">"
+ "<a:set><a:prop><b:read>" + 1
+ "</b:read></a:prop>"
+ "</a:set></a:propertyupdate>";
```